# Cannot change the boolean value to true

Tags: java, android

When I execute the code, it always goes to the else condition. But I want the if statement to run when score=true; I cannot figure out how to do this...kindly help me out.
If not this way, is there any other way I can approach?

```
public class withComp extends Activity {

 public boolean isPlayer2=false, score=false;
 @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
      setContentView(R.layout.withcomp);
      final Button one = (Button)findViewById(R.id.one); 
      final TextView winner = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.winner);

        one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
        {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) 
               {
               if(isPlayer2==false)
                  {
                one.setText("X");
                score = true;
                one.setEnabled(false);
                isPlayer2 = true;
              }
               else
               {
                  one.setText("O");
                  one.setEnabled(false);
                  isPlayer2=false;
               }
          }
   });
     if(score == true)
     {
       winner.setText("won");
     }
    else {
      winner.setText("lose");
         }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation

Comment: here `if(score == true);` remove `;` semicolon to execute if block

Comment: Does this even compile?

Answer (score 5):

Just use

```
if(score)
```

Without the comma

You don't need to write 
`if (variable == true)` or `if (variable == false)`

It's much better just to write
`if (variable)` or `if (!variable)`

Answer (score 1):

- You're executing the If-Else only once when the activity is created.
  **Move the if-else-code into the OnClickListener.**
- And of course remove the semicolon after the if.

For example:

```
public class withComp extends Activity {

  public boolean isPlayer2=false, score=false;
  @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
      setContentView(R.layout.withcomp);

      final Button one = (Button)findViewById(R.id.one); 
      final TextView winner = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.winner);

      one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
             if (!isPlayer2) {
                one.setText("X");
                score = true;
                one.setEnabled(false);
                isPlayer2 = true;
              } else {
                  one.setText("O");
                  one.setEnabled(false);
                  isPlayer2=false;
              }

              // XXX Move it here
              if (score) {
                winner.setText("won");
              } else {
                winner.setText("lose");
              }
          }
       });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in `if(score == true);`

if clauses do not need a semicolon after the condition, but a statement. Giving it a semicolon passes it the null statement, meaning nothing will happen.

After that it will execute both the blocks following, overwriting what happens in the block you intended to be executed if score is `true`.

You can fix this simply by removing the semicolon, letting it correctly execute the block.

Answer (score 0):

Semicolon means end of statement.Remove `;`

from `if(score == true);`

Answer (score 0):

Use it this way"

```
if(score){
 winner.setText("won");
}
else {
 winner.setText("lose");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a few things,

- one as already was pointed out, you are using semicolon `;` after if statement, and i'm supprised you were able to compiled and execute this code
- two, your `if-else` block is executed in method `create` and you setting value of `score` in listener, which means, block`if-else` will be executed after you create your activity, while value `score` will be setted to `true` after press button